# fit a skewed t-distribution or normal distribution in Matlab

Tags: database, matlab, statistics, distribution

I have a dataset that I know for sure that has some sort of skewness (and potentially excess kurtosis). I would like to fit this dataset to some sort of distribution, and I thought the most simplistic is to have a skewed student's t-distribution or skewed normal distribution. What sort of distribution in Matlab can I fit the data to?

Thanks!
L.

Comment: quite a lot: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/supported-distributions.html

Comment: @Benoit_11 I am interested in using the Pearson system, but I see that under the fit column it refers me to pearsrnd(), it only generates random numbers based on the 4 moments; how would I create a PDF from that?

Comment: There's no such think as a skewed normal or student's t, both are symmetric by definition.  If you want skewed distributions, look at alternatives such as beta, gamma, Weibull, log-normal,...

Answer (score 1):

There may be no `pearspdf` function in Matlab, because the seven distribution types of the [Pearson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution) mostly correspond to or are based on extant functions for other distributions:

- Type 0: [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), [`normpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html)
- Type I: [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), [`betapdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/betapdf.html)
- Type II: [Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), [`tpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tpdf.html)
- Type III: [Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), [`gampdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gampdf.html)
- Type IV: [Not related to any standard distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution#Case_1.2C_negative_discriminant:_The_Pearson_type_IV_distribution)
- Type V: [Inverse gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution), Calculated via [`gampdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gampdf.html)
- Type VI: [F-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution), [`fpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fpdf.html)
- Type VII: [Student's t-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)/[t location scale distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-scale_family), [`tpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tpdf.html)/[`prob.tLocationScaleDistribution`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.tlocationscaledistribution-class.html)

The summary above simplifies a lot of course and it would be useful to have one function that calculates your PDF according to the system, like `pearsrnd` does for random variate generation. Luckily someone has already done that and posted it on the MathWorks File Exchange: [`pearspdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26516-pearspdf).

You can also use the second argument of the `pearsrnd` function, which returns the type of the distribution in the Pearson system (see [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/generating-data-using-flexible-families-of-distributions.html) for examples). If, for example, it suggests that your data is Type III, you could attempt to fit it directly using [`gamfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gamfit.html) to estimate the parameter values. `gamfit`, and other similarly-names functions, are based on robust [maximum-likelihood estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) (MLE).